# how to hide ng-repeat div using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
.controller('CouponsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$ionicPopup','$ionicLoading',
    function($scope, $http, $window, $location, $ionicPopup,$ionicLoading) {
        
        $scope.find = function() {
    
     $http.get('').success(function(data, dealers, response) {
     
                     $scope.coupons = data;
        
                });



            }
}
])
```

```html
<div class="list card" data-ng-repeat="coupon in coupons |  filter:couponquery ">


  <div class="item item-body" style="padding:10px;">
    <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{coupon.Coupon_Image}}">
    <p style="color:green;font-weight:700">
 {{coupon.Store_Name}}
    </p>
   <p style="font-weight:700">{{coupon.Offer_Meassage}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left" >
    
   
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="apply(coupon._id,coupon.Store_ID)" id="appcolor">
      <i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled" ></i> 
      Activate
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
```

i have created 3 coupons.1st one is applicable for 10 user,2nd one is applicable
for 5 user and 3rd one is applicable for 20 user.In user page i have listed coupons with activate button  using ng-repeat.if once user activates coupon i have stored coupon id and coupondetails in one table and i have reduced the count in coupons for example user activated 1st coupon in that count(10) i have reduced 1 and 9 coupons remaining its working fine.
Expectation:
If once user activated the coupon i want to remove from ng-repeat in his/her profile or i need to change button status Activated and disabled button in that particular profile.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sreemohan143/U3pVM/18537/

Comment: Is there a question here?  This looks like a poorly formatted spew of application requirements with a plea for someone to show you how to put them together.

Comment: Can you create fiddle for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) for activated coupons.

```
<div ng-repeat="coupon in coupons" ng-hide="coupon.activated"> 
... 
</div>
```

here is updated [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7jnxcuh0/).

Answer (score 0):

Filter your `coupons` by `id` after clicking on activate link

Here is updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gt2jndjs/3/)

your activate function :

```
$scope.activate = function(coupon) {
    if(coupon.couponname.indexOf("breakfast") !== -1)
        coupon.noofcoupon--;
    if(coupon.couponname.indexOf("lunch") !== -1)
        coupon.noofcoupon--;
    if(coupon.couponname.indexOf("dinner") !== -1)
        coupon.noofcoupon--;

    if(coupon.noofcoupon === 0){
        $scope.coupons = $scope.coupons = $filter('filter')($scope.coupons,function(value, index, array) {
             return value.id !== coupon.id;
         });
     }
 }
```